# Capture Mac screen for multiple users

Tags: macos, daemon, screen-capture

I'm trying to capture the screen on a Mac with a Daemon that runs as root.

The code looks something like this:

```
activeDisplayID = CGMainDisplayID();
CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImage(activeDisplayID);
```

I works well but when I switch to another user, I continue to get the screen of the previous user - it is alive so there seem to be some higher meaning with this from Apple.

For some use cases this would be perfect but I would like to capture the screen that's actually being displayed on the monitor.

When the new user logs in, the display id returned from CGMainDisplayID() changes but I get the screen for the first user when I create the image!?

I have to stop the Daemon and start it again to get the screen from a different user. It seems like the Mac OS caches the first display access and keeps giving that to the Daemon.

Is there a way to reset this or some other workaround for this behavior?

Comment: more like you can only access screens that are associated with your account. if you could capture screens from other accounts, you'd basically be SPYING on those accounts.

Comment: The Daemon runs as root. To illustrate it in an other way, I start the Daemon (sudo launchctl load ...) in the Terminal window for user1, then switch to user2 and start capturing the screen - and I get the screen for user2. When I switch back to user1 I continue to get the screen from user2 (even with a new call to CGMainDisplayID()).